# bib2gls without sorting

Tags: glossaries-extra, bib2gls

I am using `bib2gls` to create various glossaries, each one created from a separate file using `\GlsXtrLoadResources`. I would like to be able to sort one of those glossaries by hand. Is there a way to tell `bib2gls` to sort the entries in their order of appearance in the .bib file?

Comment: I didn't try it out but the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/bib2gls.pdf) of bib2gls mentions that there is an option `sort=none` (Table 5.1 on page 230).

Comment: Thanks, zhis is it! Couldn't find it in the manual myself. If you put this as an answer I would accept it.